# Video Unavailable

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

So I'm currently trying to learn JS and use the youtube API. The problem is that when I add a video, I get the 'Video unavailable' but when I try another youtube ID, the video is fine. Is there any way to actually bypass this video unavailable?

```js
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('YouTubeBackgroundVideoPlayer', {
    //   videoId: 'SefG0gfxK6s', // YouTube Video ID
    videoId: 'njzReW9HVB4',
    width: 1920, // Player width (in px)
    height: 1080, // Player height (in px)
    playerVars: {
      playlist: 'njzReW9HVB4',
      autoplay: 1, // Auto-play the video on load
      autohide: 1,
      disablekb: 1,
      controls: 0, // Hide pause/play buttons in player
      showinfo: 0, // Hide the video title
      modestbranding: 1, // Hide the Youtube Logo
      loop: 1, // Run the video in a loop
      fs: 0, // Hide the full screen button
      autohide: 0, // Hide video controls when playing
      rel: 0,
      enablejsapi: 1
    },
    events: {
      onReady: function(e) {
        e.target.mute();
        e.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd1080');
        e.target.seekTo(279);
      },
      onStateChange: function(e) {
        if (e && e.data === 1) {
          var videoHolder = document.getElementById('home-banner-box');
          if (videoHolder && videoHolder.id) {
            videoHolder.classList.remove('loading');
          }

          var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");
          x.play();
          x.volume = 0.12;
        } else if (e && e.data === 0) {
          e.target.playVideo()
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I didn't see any issues with your code. Here is the [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSOes/hs4fx09r/).

Answer (score 2):

If other YouTube videos work with your code, then "Video Unavailable" probably means that it's an issue with the specific video you're trying to play. If it's your own video, try  removing any tags or names in your description or anything else that may be construed as copy-written material, saving it, and trying again.